# Timepicker (ngx-bootstrap) change meridian (PM/AM) style (color/background)

Tags: angular, timepicker, ngx-bootstrap

I'm using ngx-bootstrap's Timepicker and in need to change the background of Meridian (AM/PM) and preferably the spacing between Minutes and Meridian. 
All I have is:

```
<timepicker [(ngModel)]="myTime"></timepicker>
```

There is no option for configuration like in Datepicker (bsConfig) or Themes, and the component is using a HTML TABLE to build it. 
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Try to solve it yourself and limit your question to specific problem. I bet it has some classes when it's AM or PM. Just inspect the DOM. Try to set different time and see what changes, then add your custom CSS based on that.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but for anyone else...

```
::ng-deep td > .mat-focus-indicator.mat-button.mat-stroked-button.mat-button-base {
background-color: lightblue;color: white;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you married to using NGX Bootstrap?  I would suggest migrating to ng-bootstrap's timepicker, as it offers meridian support and the css can be easily manipulated.

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/timepicker/examples

Comment: unfortunately I do. I'm actually removing ng-bootstrap to use ngx.